# Denying access to sound device

Tags: windows-10, audio

I'm having serious sound issues with Dirt 3. Is there a way to deny it from accessing my sound device in Windows 10? Muting in audio mixer isn't a solution. The device is a Steelseries Siberia 150 USB headset.

Answer (score 0):

By denying access to the sound device I am assuming you don't want to hear the sounds from the game. You can mute the game by:

1. On your taskbar there is a icon that is for sound. Right click the icon and click volume mixer.
2. On the window that pops up you can lower or mute each program that is playing sound's volume.
3. Select your application and drag the volume to your desired amount, in this case drag your game's volume all the way down to mute it.

Comment: No, I didn't mean muting. The problem with the game is that every few seconds it disables my headphones for few seconds, so my idea was to not let the game use it at all, or maybe somehow create a virtual sound device and force the game to use it while using the headset for everything else. Is there a way to do that?